# React Measurement Image with draw line as ruler

Tags: reactjs, image, annotations, measurement, rulers

[image]

I searched react library for measurement object annotation on images, library react-measurements can't use on the mobile browsers, cause the library triggering mouse cursor. Can anyone help me to measure draw with line-like images on top?